# base64 to json property in Python

Tags: python, azure-functions

I have the following code:

```
data = open('/tmp/books_read.png', "rb").read()
    encoded = base64.b64encode(data)
    retObj = {"groupedImage": encoded}
    return func.HttpResponse(
                json.dumps(retObj),
                mimetype="application/json",
                status_code=200)
```

... and it throws the following error:

```
Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable Stack
```

May I know how do I fix this?

Comment: `encoded = base64.b64encode(data).decode()` will give you back a string which will normally parse (b64encode - encode as b64 in bytes object, decode - change bytes object to str). Because b64 is ASCII it can be freely converted from bytes to str (unicode) and back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`base64.b64encode(data)` will output an object in bytes

`encoded = base64.b64encode(data).decode()` converts it to string

after that you might need (quite common) to do url encoding to the string

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
urlencode({"groupedImage": encoded})
```

Comment: urlencode was not needed it works just with .decode() thanks:-)

Comment: You might also consider specifying the encoding type as an option if it is not UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

If it is image which you want to send as http reponse you shouldn't be doing json.dumps , instead you can send raw bytes and receive it.

However if you still want to do you'll need to change to `json.dumps(str(retObj))`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `encoded = base64.b64encode(data).decode()`

`b64encode()` will encode as base64

`x.decode()` will decode bytes object to unicode string